# HierarchicalDataTemplate Reference TreeViewItem from Converter

Tags: binding, treeview, converters, treeviewitem

I have the need to adjust the margin of my treeviewitems according to the height of the parent treeviewitem.  I tried to add a converter to the stackpanel in the hierarchicaldatatemplate but it doesn't give me any way to accessing the treeviewitem in the converter convertTo method.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

    <converter:LocationConverter x:Name="LocationConverter1" x:Key="LocationConverter1" />

    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1" ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategory}">

            <StackPanel Margin="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LocationConverter1}}">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

            </StackPanel>

        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <custom:TreeViewExtended x:Name="TopicsTreeView"  
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"/>

    <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click" Margin="200"></Button>



</Grid>
```

Is there any way of passing the treeView instance as a converterParameter into the convertTo method so I can find the treeviewitems by name from within the converter method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a good way to put the TreeView instance as a ConverterParameter ([Googling ConverterParameter](http://www.google.com/search?q=ConverterParameter) yields [some](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/88a22766-5e6f-4a16-98a6-1ab39877dd09) [interesting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/453429bd-a403-4e82-8666-814bf2a514a9) [ideas](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7298ceb5-bf56-47aa-a161-5dd99189408b) on how to [achieve this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/4c98f262-5653-419f-8581-6b4091de484b)...), but I think your approach is wrong - instead of passing the entire tree view to the converter and then find TreeViewItems by name, why not pass the TreeViewItem to the Margin binding with a converter that will search the visual tree and find the required height?

This can be done like this:

```
<StackPanel Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                            AncestorType=TreeViewItem},
                             Converter={StaticResource LocationConverter1}}">
```

Now, your converter's value parameter will be the current **TreeViewItem**. From this value, you can get the TreeView instance or, even better, the parent TreeViewItem (if such exist) using the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx).